# .Net Oracle.ManagedDataAccess Exception Handling (ORA-00001: unique constraint (x) violated)

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net, oracle.manageddataaccess

I want to detect ORA-0001 from my .net application which uses Oracle.ManagedDataAccess client to connect to Oracle.

When I inspect the details of OracleException which was throwed when constraint violated, that is What I see;

[image]

I could not find a better way for detecting constraint violation other then parsing the Message property of exception.

[image]

What is the best practice of that ? Any better, convenient way appricated.

P.S : I dont want to write pl/sql for that.

Thanks

Comment: You can also use the `Number` property. It will give you the number of Oracle specific error.

Comment: It seems to related ORA-[Number], thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text.